# Will Divshot offer any type of commenting features so clients or collaborators can add feedback like in Easel.io?

Tags: divshot

We really like Divshot. Our issue is we can't seem to find any type of commenting feature so clients/collaborators can add feedback. We would like to know if this is a feature that is coming soon to Divshot?

Answer (score 0):

It's something that's been on our radar. What would you like to see in it?

Comment: Thank you for the response! We have been using this app called invisionapp.com for our psd mocks and they have a great commenting system. You are allowed to click on spots on the page and add a comment. The team is allowed to see comments and re-comment on them. There is a revision comment history. You can mark it as complete and read. You can see all comments, which ones are open, finished or which are dev note comments. You can notify your team or particular person. So it works really well internally and with clients when sending for feedback.